# how to list images older than 90 days in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

One of my GCP projects have lots of images accumulated over the time and I want to delete all the images older than 90 days. Does anyone knows what's the best way? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set lifecycle rules on your GCS bucket. Select your bucket then click on **LIFECYCLE**.

[image: 1]

Click on **ADD A RULE**

[image: 2]

Under **Select an action**, select **Delete Object**, then under **Select object conditions**, select **Age**. Enter `90` for value as you want to delete all images older than 90 days.

[image: 3]

Click [image: 4]

Your GCS bucket rule should appear like this:

[image: 5]